# Redshift Scheduled Query Setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam

I'm having trouble getting the IAM role setup to work for a Redshift scheduled query.

I created a role `redshift-scheduled-query` that looks like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "events.amazonaws.com",
                    "redshift.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

It also has the following permission policies:

- AmazonEventBridgeFullAccess
- AmazonRedshiftAllCommandsFullAccess
- AmazonRedshiftDataFullAccess
- AmazonRedshiftFullAccess
- AmazonRedshiftQueryEditor
- AmazonRedshiftQueryEditorV2FullAccess

Is there something else I'm missing? I also added `redshift-scheduled-query` as an associated role to my redshift cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the following trust policy for the role I created worked:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "redshift.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::134776740825:user/user_name"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the principal for the Redshift scheduler: `scheduler.redshift.amazonaws.com`. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/APIReference/API_ScheduledAction.html for details.